# Save data using WEB API POST method in asp.net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

HOW TO Post data to my Database(SQL Server) using WEB API POST method in asp.net c#.help me to find out.

thanks inadvance

Comment: Do you want to expose a POST method using web API?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery,$.ajax() Will help U better.

Javascript:

```
var employee= { Id:1, Name:"Dhiren" }
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8036/api/employee/add',
    data: JSON.stringify(employee),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ console.log(data) }
});
```

Model:-

```
Public class Employee
{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Web Api Controller:-
In Web Api:-U can Use [HttpPost]

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Add(Employee employee)
{
    var strMessage="Hello:- " + employee.Name;
    return Ok(strMessage);
}
```

In New Version Web Api 2:-U directly action method without [HttpPost].Its user methos like pefix.

```
public IHttpActionResult Add(Employee employee)
{
      var strMessage="Hello:- " + employee.Name;
    return Ok(strMessage);
}
```

Hope its work !!!